# Skewness in Stata

Tags: stata

I have tried many different combinations of `sktest` and sadly nothing works.

I was almost certain that `sktest` will work with `by` combination but it doesn't.

The issue is: I have binary data `gender` (male 0 and female 1) and I want to measure the skewness of returns for each (male and female) in the variable `returns`. Can you please advise?

I was hoping for a result similar to what we get when we run e.g. `by gender: summarize returns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different questions are bundled together here.

**Testing**

If you want to run `sktest` for different groups, you can just repeat the command

```
 sysuse auto, clear 
 sktest price if foreign == 1 
 sktest price if foreign == 0
```

or write your own wrapper program to do the same. `sktest` in essence shows P-values but no summary measures.

Or do something like this:

```
 preserve 
 statsby , by(foreign) : sktest price
 list
 restore
```

**Measuring**

If you want to see (moment-based) skewmess measures, you can just repeat `summarize`

```
 bysort foreign: summarize price, detail
```

A wrapper is already available on SSC that is more selective.

```
 moments price, by(foreign) 

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Group |          n        mean          SD    skewness    kurtosis
  ----------+-----------------------------------------------------------
   Domestic |         52    6072.423    3097.104       1.778       5.090
    Foreign |         22    6384.682    2621.915       1.215       3.555
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.
**Warnings**

1. Stata uses one estimator for moment-based skewness. There are others.
2. There are many ways to measure skewness. Those others mentioned in Section 7 of [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211063415) are not a complete list; perhaps the most important omission is L-skewness (see `lmoments` from SSC).